# Where to implement pre-processing in PyTorch Lightning (e.g. tokenizing input text)

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Is there a convention to implement some kind of `predict()` method in PyTorch Lightning that does pre-processing before performing the actual prediction using `forward()`?

In my case, I have a text classifier consisting of an embedding layer and a few fully connected layers. The text needs to be tokenized before being passed to the embedding layer. During training and evaluation the `LightningDataModule`'s `setup()` method does the job.

Now, I'm wondering what the best practice for inference during production is. I could add a `predict()` method to my `LightningModule` where I could write the same pre-processing code as in `LightningDataModule.setup()`. But, of course, I do not want to duplicate the code.

In [this community example](https://github.com/ricardorei/lightning-text-classification) project linked in the official PyTorch Lightning docs, the authors define a `prepare_sample()` function in the `LightningModule` that is used by their `predict()` function, and is also passed to the `LightningDataModule`.

Is this the right way to handle pre-processing? Also, why is there no `prepare_sample()` or `predict()` in [`LightningModule`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pytorch_lightning.core.lightning.html#module-pytorch_lightning.core.lightning)? To me, this seems like a common use case, for example:

```py
model = load_model('data/model.ckpt')  # load pre-trained model, analyzes user reviews

user_input = input('Your movie review > ')

predicted_rating = model.predict(user_input)  # e.g. "I liked the movie pretty much." -> 4 stars

print('Predicted rating: %s/5 stars' % predicted_rating)
```

Now that I think about it, `predict()` should also process the result from `forward()` the same way the evaluation code does, like selecting the class with the highest output or selecting all classes with outputs larger than some threshold - some more code that should not be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a `LightningModule` if the code should be for production? If the model is finished you only need to load the model from memory and define the preprocess steps.

The repository you refer to have implemented the predict, and prepare_sample on top of the LightningModule.

In my opinion pytorch-lightning is for training and evaluation of the model and not for production. We would not want to keep the analytics and debugging when sending a model to production so instead we create a slimmed version which only have loading of model, preprocess and prediction.

Towardsdatascience have a small code example: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-pytorch-lightning-models-to-production-7e887d69109f

Comment: Good point, the `LightningModule`, `DataModule`, etc. should not make it into production. Also, great link. Still, I usually also implement a prompt to accept inputs interactively for testing and demo purposes during development. Would be nice to have a guideline there.

Comment: You mean like the test method? Otherwise you can just send some data to the model from the trainer when it have finished training.

Comment: `Trainer.test()`? Interesting idea. Currently I use it only for my final evaluation by running `trainer.test(model, data_module)`. But creating a `DataModule` whose `prepare_data()` would be called for every interactive prediction seems a bit overkill. Sure, I could pass a `DataLoader` to `trainer.test(model, data_loader)`, but then again, I would have to duplicate the pre-processing code to create the one-sample dataset for the `DataLoader`.

Comment: Send some data to the test_dataloader? When you call Trainer.test() it will be called in turn. Alternative send in a custom dataloader too test and it will use that.

Comment: Well, creating the test `DataLoader` requires a pre-processed dataset (`DataSet` or `List[]`). That pre-processing code is located in my `DataModule.prepare_data()` where I build the datasets for my `DataLoader`s from my data files on disk. Now, I would like not to duplicate that pre-processing code. I'd really appreciate a code example, but unfortunately most examples simply duplicate the code or do stuff I don't feel comfortable with like in the example referenced in the question.

Comment: What about creating a torch dataset and then load it with dataloader? If that part handles the data loading and preprocessing you only need to specify the dataloader within either lightningmodule or lightningdatamodule.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help me out! I will further consider it when I continue working on the code in question.